# Search a Redis Database

Tags: select, condition, redis

Imagine having a tun of hashes in a Redis Database, each representing a user object. How would you get the user with for example the lowest registration date? The user where `ts_registered` is the lowest. I searched a bit on the [Commands Page on redis.io](http://redis.io/commands) but didn't seem to find a command for it there.

I don't have much experience with Redis and I'm basically just checking out how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Redis doesn't come out of the box with the ability to search/index inside hashes, but it gives you all the tools you need to accomplish your task. Your challenge could be solved, for example, by keeping a key in the database called last_user_registered or similar, and SETting it every time that a user registers to that user's ID. When you want to fetch the last user that had registered at any given moment - just GET it, get it?

But you (and Redis!) can do much better: for example, you could use a Redis list and LPUSH/RPOP members to keep scores with the users who last joined. Or, you could use a sorted set where each member is a user id and the score is the timestamp... ah, the possibilities are endless and you're only limited by your imagination (and time, resources, etc...) ;)

I think this is exactly why Redis 'aficionados' lovingly refer to it as a database building tool rather than as just a database - you can actually make it do whatever you want and if what you want isn't in Redis already, there's always [Lua](http://redis.io/commands/eval) that you can use to extend with or even developing your own fork and putting in a pull request to the [github](https://github.com/antirez/redis).